# Include multiple javascript files in a JS file

Tags: javascript

So, if I have to include a Javascript file in a .js file, I use to below script. It works fine.

```
var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onload = function() {

  //Some code

};
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

What should I do If I need to include more than 1 files.

Comment: You'd do the same thing. But it's better just to include it in the HTML of the JS file your referencing for the original JS file.

Comment: Create a reusable function?

Comment: Take a step back and learn what each line of the code shown is actually doing.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/950087/218196)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a function and pass the js files you want to include like so:

```js
        function scriptLoader(path, callback)
        {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.async = true;
            script.src = path;
            script.onload = function(){
                if(typeof(callback) == "function")
                {
                    callback();
                }
            }
            try
            {
                var scriptOne = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                scriptOne.parentNode.insertBefore(script, scriptOne);
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
            }
        }
```

And call it like so:

```
scriptLoader('/path/to/file.js');
```

in the similar manner you can call as many JS file you like this:

```
scriptLoader('/path/to/file2.js');
scriptLoader('/path/to/file3.js');
```

and even with onload callback functions like so:

```
scriptLoader('/path/to/file6.js',function(){
    alert('file6 loaded');
});
```

Comment: Great. This is a better implementation of what I could do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you'd do the same as you've got there but just change the variable name from  `var script` to something like `var scriptA` and change the code that follows to match like `script.src =` to `scriptA.src =`

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You could reuse the same variable for multiple scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This function will load one script or many, pass a single file or an array of many:

```
function include(src, cb) {
  arr = (src instanceof Array) ? src : [{
    'src': src,
    'cb': cb
  }];
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    _include(item.src, item.cb);
  })

  function _include(src, cb) {
    var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.src = src;
    script.async = true;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.onload = function() {
      if (cb) cb()
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  }
}

include("/js/file1.js");
include("/js/file1.js", function(){console.log("file1 loaded")});
include([{src:"/js/file1.js"},{src:"/js/file2.js"},{src:"/js/file3.js"}]);
```